# gorm select and returns a column in the form of a slice

Tags: go, go-gorm

Is there gorm has the method to do this like something in PHP ?

```
$name = $db->column("name");
// output of $name: ["joe", "john", .....]
print_r($name);
```

What I want to do (fake code):

```
var ct []string
db.Model("user").Column(&ct)
// output of ct: []string{"joe", "john", .....}
fmt.println(ct)
```

Or I must get result with strcut and then format to slice?

**gorm version: `v1.21.11`**

Answer (score 4):

Create a type with the field you want to grab and and declare an array with that newly created type.

```
type name string
var arr []name

// with table
err := db.Table("your table name").Select("name").Find(&arr).Error

// with model field
err := db.Model(User{}).Select("name").Find(&arr).Error
```

You can look into the gorm's official documentation:
https://gorm.io/docs/advanced_query.html#Smart-Select-Fields

Comment: how to do this for 2 columns in the same query?

Comment: Need to declare an array of struct. you may use the model's struct or create a custom type as per your use case. you may look into this documentation https://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Retrieving-all-objects